# What is the custom command to "Show Desktop" for hot corners?

Tags: release-juno, hot-corners, show-desktop

[image: What is the custom command to "Show Desktop" for hot corners?]

I wanted to have a "Show Desktop" like in the windows ( when I point the mouse to bottom right corner it will show the desktop )

Comment: If it helps, you can use a `'minimize-current'` setting with dconf or with `gsettings set` in a hot corner and hit the corner several times to do this. Also, there's a Show Desktop icon you can put on the dock.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to run a command after leaving a hot corner, but you can toggle "Show Desktop" when you touch a hot corner.

I've got the following script from [this](https://www.tech-spy.co.uk/2018/09/how-to-add-show-desktop-icon-to-ubuntu-dock/) article:

1. You first need to install wmctrl (`sudo apt install wmctrl`)
2. Save the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
status="$(wmctrl -m | grep "showing the desktop" | sed -r 's/(.*)(ON|OFF)/\2/g')"

if [ $status == "ON" ]; then
wmctrl -k off
else
wmctrl -k on
fi
```

3. Make it executable: `chmod +x /Path/to/script.sh`
4. Set the command for the hot corner to `/Path/to/script.sh`

This will check if the desktop is currently shown and toggle it using wmctrl:

[image: Demo]